# Kafka : distribute process and storage

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am looking for a solution to distribute treatments with kafka.
I have to do some calculation on millions of independent entries.
So i installed 3 kafka brokers on 3 different VMs and start producing with 3 different thread data to a 3 partitions' topic. The idea was then to consume those partitions with 3 consumers in the same consumer group, and store the result in another topic for other process.
Sadly it ended up storing everything on only one partition, so on only one VM. I need the storage and the processing to be distributed...

Is it possible to produce data to different topics in a complete parallel way? 
It would be even better if I could with 1 producer send approximately the same amount of data to each partition every X minutes.

I am using the java kafka-clients 0.10.2.0 with kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0 brokers.

Thank you

Comment: Your set up seems correct, how do you know the messages go through only one partition ? Also can you show us the result of this command : `bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper ZOOKEEPER:2181 --topic TOPIC`

Comment: I know it went to only one partition because the size of /tmp/kafka-logs/ only went up in one computer and didnt change at all on others. Here is the result of the command : Topic:Trajectoires PartitionCount:3 ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
 Topic: Trajectoires Partition: 0 Leader: 2 Replicas: 2 Isr: 2
 Topic: Trajectoires Partition: 1 Leader: 3 Replicas: 3 Isr: 3
 Topic: Trajectoires Partition: 2 Leader: 2 Replicas: 2 Isr: 2

Comment: First you can see that you only have 2 brokers used because Leaders are 2 or 3. You should have one broker for one partition if you want to achieve what you want.

Comment: How can I update the leader of partitions ? I guess I created my topics when one of the broker was down and it didnt change since then

Comment: When I check on a partition that I created just now, all 3 partitions have a different leader

Comment: And is it possible to have only one producer, to produce information to 3 different topics?

Comment: You can delete your topic and create it again.
I have never tried to have one producer producing on different topics but I think it is possible. However, it is totally possible to have one producer to one topic (with 3 partitions) and then have 3 parallel consumers (each on one partition).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data is partitioned by key. Thus, if all you records have the same key, they will all go to the same partition.

You can either specify the partitions you want to write to explicitly on the producer, or you use `null`-keys that will result in random distribution.